# POSTing single object or array of objects in play 2.x with Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I am adding a POST endpoint to the application that I am building with Scala on Play 2.4 platform.

I want it to be able to accept a single object or an array of objects (same objects) so that the client can do bulk post if needed (imaging adding 10 employees at time, or just one).

I have done this with case matching, but it doesn't look as elegant as Scala should look. Does anyone have any ideas please?

Comment: Please post more code about what you've tried so far, what did you expect and what did you get.

Comment: Do you have something like `POST   /        controllers.MyController.myService(ids: List[Int])`

Comment: Also, when you say "accept a single object or an array of objects" you mean in the body of the request, right?